# Ext.Component: Template's afterrender fails to access renderSelectors

Tags: javascript, extjs, scope

Below, you will find two examples using the template-render pattern. Example A does not work correctly. The value `cmp.helloLiEl` is `undefined` in the listener function. The `afterrender` callback does not know about the `renderSelectors`.

In Example B, the `afterrender` is assigned an inline function to attach a listener to the template list item. I thought that supplying the function with the scope would suffice, but this did not work as expected.

How can I get Example A's `onRender` listener to access the `renderSelectors`?

## Example A

```js
Ext.onReady(function() {
  Ext.define('Exmple.component.Hello', {
    extend: 'Ext.Component',
    title: 'Hello Test',
    renderTpl: [
      '<ul>',
      '<li class="lang" id="helloSelector-li">Hello {name}!</li>',
      '</ul>'
    ],
    renderData: {
      name: 'Joe'
    },
    renderSelectors: {
      helloLiEl: '#helloSelector-li'
    },
    listeners: {
      afterrender: {
        fn : this.onRender,
        scope : this
      }
    },
    onRender: function(cmp) {
      console.log(cmp.helloLiEl);
      cmp.mon(cmp.helloLiEl, 'click', function() {
        alert('Hello again...');
      });
    }
  });

  Ext.create('Exmple.component.Hello', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    renderData: {
      name: 'Bob'
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#helloSelector-li {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 35px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.1.1-gpl/resources/css/ext-all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.1.1-gpl/ext-all.js"></script>
```

## Example B

```js
Ext.onReady(function() {
  Ext.define('Exmple.component.Hello', {
    extend: 'Ext.Component',
    title: 'Hello Test',
    renderTpl: [
      '<ul>',
        '<li class="lang" id="helloSelector-li">Hello {name}!</li>',
      '</ul>'
    ],
    renderData: {
      name: 'Joe'
    },
    renderSelectors: {
      helloLiEl: '#helloSelector-li'
    },
    listeners: {
      afterrender: function(cmp) {
        console.log(cmp.helloLiEl);
        cmp.mon(cmp.helloLiEl, 'click', function() {
          alert('Hello again...');
        });
      }
    }
  });

  Ext.create('Exmple.component.Hello', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    renderData: {
      name: 'Bob'
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#helloSelector-li {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 35px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.1.1-gpl/resources/css/ext-all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.1.1-gpl/ext-all.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is your scope.

Also the `onRender` function is overriding the method of the same name which it inherits (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.util.Renderable-method-onRender) so hence I have changed the function name to `myTest`

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.define('Exmple.component.Hello', {
        extend: 'Ext.Component',
        title: 'Hello Test',
        renderTpl: ['<ul>', '<li class="lang" id="helloSelector-li">Hello {name}!</li>', '</ul>'],
        renderData: {
            name: 'Joe'
        },
        renderSelectors: {
            helloLiEl: '#helloSelector-li'
        },

        initComponent: function() {
            me = this;
            me.listeners = {
                afterrender: {
                    fn: this.myTest,
                    scope: this
                }
            }
            this.callParent();
        },
        myTest: function(cmp) {
            cmp.mon(cmp.helloLiEl, 'click', function() {
                alert('Hello again...');
            });
        }
    });

    Ext.create('Exmple.component.Hello', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        renderData: {
            name: 'Bob'
        }
    });
});
```

Have a look at the answer added here https://stackoverflow.com/a/23806475

Demo: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/gqj